# Java - Sockets - display names of all files on server

Tags: java, sockets, ftp, rfc

I'm trying to make ftpclient which will use only sockets. I'm making a connection with server but I don't have idea how to display files. Here is my code:

```
package pl.edu.ftp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.*;

import pl.edu.config.ConfigData;

public class FTPProtocol {
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private OutputStreamWriter writer;
    private Socket socket2;
    private BufferedReader reader2;
    private OutputStreamWriter writer2;
    private String serverImportantOutput;
    private boolean firstSocket = true;

    public void makeConnection(ConfigData configData) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        socket = new Socket(configData.getServerAddress(), configData.getPort());
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

        (new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String line;
                    if (firstSocket == true) {
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println("SERVER: " + line);
                            if (line.startsWith("227 Entering Passive Mode")) {
                                serverImportantOutput = line;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println("SERVER: " + line);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        })).start();

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        sendCommand("USER " + configData.getUsername());
        sendCommand("PASS " + configData.getPassword());
        sendCommand("SYST");
        sendCommand("FEAT");
        sendCommand("PWD");
        sendCommand("TYPE I");

        sendCommand("PWD");
        List<String> newData = sendCommandPasv("PASV");
        socket2 = new Socket(newData.get(0), Integer.parseInt(newData.get(1)));
        reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket2.getInputStream()));
        writer2 = new OutputStreamWriter(socket2.getOutputStream());

        sendCommand2("LIST");
    }

    private void sendCommand(String command) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        firstSocket = true;

        writer.write(command + "\r\n");
        writer.flush();
        System.out.println("Client:" + command);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    private void sendCommand2(String command) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        firstSocket = true;
        writer2.write(command + "\r\n");
        writer2.flush();
        System.out.println("Client:" + command);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        firstSocket = false;
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    private List<String> sendCommandPasv(String command) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

        writer.write(command + "\r\n");
        writer.flush();
        System.out.println("Client:" + command);
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        String fullAdress = serverImportantOutput.substring(serverImportantOutput.indexOf("(") + 1,
                serverImportantOutput.indexOf(")"));
        List<String> partsOfAdress = Arrays.asList(fullAdress.replaceAll("\\s+", "").split(","));

        String host = partsOfAdress.get(0) + "." + partsOfAdress.get(1) + "." + partsOfAdress.get(2) + "."
                + partsOfAdress.get(3);
        String port = Integer
                .toString(Integer.parseInt(partsOfAdress.get(4)) * 256 + Integer.parseInt(partsOfAdress.get(5)));

        System.out.println("Host: " + host);
        System.out.println("Port: " + port);

        listOfStrings.add(host);
        listOfStrings.add(port);

        return listOfStrings;
    }
}
```

I tried to use LIST, NLST, MLSD but still nothing work. In console I have:

```
SERVER: 227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,197,183)
Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 50615
Client:LIST
```

And "Client:LIST" I have to wait very long. After that I got:

```
SERVER: 421 Connection timed out.
```

Somebody have maybe any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

I edited now this method:

```
private void sendCommand2(String command) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        writer.write(command + "\r\n");
        writer.flush();
        System.out.println("Client:" + command);
        firstSocket = false;
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
```

And now as result I have:

```
SERVER: 227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,196,72)
Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 50248
Client:LIST
SERVER: 150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/"
SERVER: 226 Successfully transferred "/"
```

But it still doesn't display any files.

---

Now I edited to read from reader2 when "bool firstSocket" is false. So it should read from "reader2" after sending "LIST" command, but it still display nothing.

```
(new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String line;
                    if (firstSocket == true) {
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println("SERVER: " + line);
                            if (line.startsWith("227 Entering Passive Mode")) {
                                serverImportantOutput = line;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        while ((line = reader2.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println("SERVER: " + line);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        })).start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to connect to the IP/port returned in the `PASV` response only after receiving `1xx` response to the `LIST` command.

You have to send the `LIST` command to the (main) control connection, not to the data connection.

Read [RFC 959](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc959) for details.